# I have problem with Linq. Where is not found

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I want to use this code - it works

```
return ToBllEntity(UnitOfWork.RankingOfFriend.GetAll().Where(s => s.PersonId == id));
```

But I want to use the same, and I have the problem

> Could not find an implementation of the query template for the source type "IGenericRepository <>". "Where" not found.

```
var res = ToBllEntity(from person in UnitOfWork.RankingOfFriend where person.id == id select person);
```

Comment: Which linq implementation are you using? Linq to entity?

Comment: I think so. UnitOfWork.RankingOfFriend is my Property from IUnitOfWork
 IGenericRepository<RankingOfFriend> RankingOfFriend { get; }

Comment: Shouldn't it be `in UnitOfWork.RankingOfFriend**.GetAll()** where`?

Comment: Realy. It is work. Thank you. I am new in EF